# Caption length widening table kable extra + latex

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

**Problem:** My tables built with the wonderful `kableExtra`package look like this:

[image]

How can I force the caption to be several lines if necessary adjusting to the minimum width of the table and not the other way around?

```
carbon_benefits%>%
  set_names(c("Year","Date","Canary","Total","Date","Canary","Total"))%>%
kable(
    caption = "\\label{tab:carbon_costs}Carbon sequestration values over time.",
    booktabs = T,
    escape = F,
    linesep= "") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position"))%>%
  add_header_above(c("","Lower"=3,"Higher"=3))%>%
  footnote(general=paste("Combining the totals for all years for both species yields a lower bound of ",round(sum(carbon_benefits$total_lower),digits=0)," and a higher bound of ",round(sum(carbon_benefits$total_upper),digits=0),".",sep = ""),
           footnote_as_chunk = T)
```

Created on 2018-07-18 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Not really relevant - why are you using `paste()` with `sep=""` rather than just use `paste0()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str_wrap` from the `stringr` package to wrap the text into a reasonable line length:

```
footnote(general=
  stringr::str_wrap(paste0("Combining the totals for all years for both species yields a lower bound of ",round(sum(carbon_benefits$total_lower),digits=0)," and a higher bound of ",round(sum(carbon_benefits$total_upper),digits=0),"."), 
    width=txtwidth), 
  footnote_as_chunk = T)
```

txtwidth can then be set to be a calculation of a reasonable length based on the expected number of columns. That depends on your data structure. Looks like about 5-6 chars per column in this case, so 35-40 characters?

Comment: Thanks @doviod also for the paste0.